# how to join mysql database with one ROW be grouped and others not

Tags: php, html, sql, database, group-by

please help me to solve this

this is my inner join sql now

```
SELECT sidebar.id_sidebar, sidebar.name_sidebar, sub_sidebar.name_sub_sidebar 
FROM (sidebar INNER JOIN 
      sub_sidebar
      ON sidebar.id_sidebar=sub_sidebar.id_sub
     )
 order by id_sidebar
```

what i want to accomplishe is,i want to group name_sidebar
example:
now my output is like this:

```
navbar
 -navbarLeft
navbar
 -navbarRight
```

what i want is:

```
NAVBAR
-navleft
-navright
```

[image]

ane here is looked of my output now

please help...

Comment: I'm baffled.  What does you data look like?  What do you want to accomplish?

Comment: i have put my output image there sir..what i want is group/distinct main collapse list..and show all the list item..example NAVBAR show navbarleft and navbar right

Comment: . . This type of transformation should be done at the application level.

Comment: omg..how stupid i am...thanks sir..my mistake to ask this dumb question...

Answer (score 0):

Try it ..

Try  to hardcode name_sub_sidebar like 'left' value property from bellow the query.

```
SELECT sidebar.id_sidebar, sidebar.name_sidebar, 'left' as name_sub_sidebar 
FROM (sidebar INNER JOIN 
      sub_sidebar
      ON sidebar.id_sidebar=sub_sidebar.id_sub
     )
 order by id_sidebar
```